# url.Action(controller, action) not routing as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes, href

In my ASP.NET MVC 3, I am using this code

```
<a href=@url.Action("myController", "myaction")>
```

But when I click on it, it does't go to my action. Instead, in the URL I see this

```
http://localhost:1402/?Length=2
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Edit :

Here are my routes :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: please include your routes from Global.asax.cs - and can you confirm that the above Url.Action call is *exactly* the same?  This usually happens when a string is passed as an argument that is expected to be a `routeValues` object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the first argument is interpretted as the Action

```
@url.Action("myaction","myController")
```

Answer (score 4):

The signature of Url.Action is:

```
Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName)
```

According to your code, the order of your parameters are incorrect, you should try:

```
@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")
```

Also remember that to remove the "Controller" part of the controller, for exemple, if I have a CustomerController with a Index action that would be like that:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Customer")
```

Comment: yes you're right - but I'm not sure the code we have been given is actually accurate, because the `string, string` overload would still render a Url without a query string.

Answer (score 1):

I've had same problem... 
My solution:

`@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "myAction", "myController", new { id=item.ID }, null)`

Just adding null to last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For default action ( action that is not defined in route ), normal HTTP GET will automagically go to, you just need to use *null* action.

@Url.Action( null, "Customer" )